# Prove that a $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix with cosinuses is invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have to prove that matrix $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cos(x_0) & \cos(2x_0) & … & \cos(nx_0) \\
    1 & \cos(x_1) & \cos(2x_1) & … & \cos(nx_1) \\
    ... & ... & … & ... \\
    1 & \cos(x_n) & \cos(2x_n) & … & \cos(nx_n) \\ 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

is invertible. I know that $$ 0 \le x_0 \lt x_1 \lt x_2 \lt … \lt x_n \lt \pi $$

so all the elements in the second column are different and decreasing. But the same cannot be said about the other columns.

I don't think that calculating the determinant is a good idea here, I tried to prove that columns\rows are independent, but I didn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: Use \times for $\times$ in $\rm\LaTeX$! It is superior to escaping an `x` and vastly superior to writing $x$.

Comment: Maybe you should try something by induction. Then using a determinant could be less daunting.

Comment: The characterization which comes to mind here is that $\cos(n x)$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial in $\cos(x)$; specifically, $\cos(n x)=T_n(\cos x)$ where $T_n(u)$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. The statement should then be that the last column, whose entries are degree $n$ polynomials in  the cosines, cannot be written as a linear combination of the other columns (whose entries all have degree less than $n$).

Comment: If we can use complex numbers here, it might help to consider the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha_0 & \alpha_0^2 & \dots & \alpha_0^n\\
1 & \alpha_1 & \alpha_1^2 & \dots & \alpha_1^n\\
1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_2^2 & \dots & \alpha_2^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
1 & \alpha_n & \alpha_n^2 & \dots & \alpha_n^{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\alpha_j = e^{ijx_0}$.

Comment: An additional observation in my previous vein: If I let $u_k:=\cos x_k$ and compute the determinant of this matrix in Mathematica, I seem to get $\prod_{j<k} (u_k-u_j)$ which is manifestly negative (and therefore the matrix is not singular). That's very much in the vein of the Vandermonde matrix and so @Omnomnomnom's suggestion seems altogether pertinent.

Comment: Finally, it seems like the restriction to $x_n<\pi$ is unnecessary: $x_n=\pi$ seems entirely appropriate as well.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant

$$D_{n+1} = \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & \cos(x_0) & \cos(2x_0) & … & \cos(nx_0) \\
    1 & \cos(x_1) & \cos(2x_1) & … & \cos(nx_1) \\
    ... & ... & … & ... \\
    1 & \cos(x_n) & \cos(2x_n) & … & \cos(nx_n) \\ 
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Can be written as 
$$D_{n+1} = \begin{vmatrix}
    T_0(y_0) & T_1(y_0) & T_2(y_0) & … & T_n(y_0) \\
    T_0(y_1) & T_1(y_1) & T_2(y_1) & … & T_n(y_1) \\
    ... & ... & … & ... \\
    T_0(y_n) & T_1(y_n) & T_2(y_n) & … & T_n(y_n) \\ 
    \end{vmatrix}
$$ where $T_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and $y_i = \cos(x_i)$ according to [Multiple-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html).

And the last determinant is a constant multiple of $\prod_{1\leq j < k\leq n}(y_j-y_k)$, since it is a polynomial in the variables $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ with degree $\binom{n}{2} = 1 + 2 + \dots + n$ which vanishes if $y_j=y_k$ for some $j\neq k$.

As $$ 0 \le x_0 \lt x_1 \lt x_2 \lt … \lt x_n \lt \pi ,$$ we have $y_j \neq y_k$ for $j \neq k$. Hence the determinant is not zero and the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the last determinant is a non-zero multiple of that product?

Comment: The determinant has the same degree and the same roots as that product, so the two indeed must be constant multiples of another (fundamental theorem of algebra). The only thing one should confirm is that the determinant doesn't vanish identically.

Comment: @Semiclassical right, which is precisely what I'm asking. I'm trying to exclude the case that the determinant is zero times your polynomial, i.e. identically zero.

Comment: Fair point. It's not my answer and I don't immediately see how to check that either. An obvious route would be to find a special case where it's obvious that the determinant is nonzero, but I've yet to find an easy one. Or, to put it another way: The answer thus far shows that, if the matrix is invertible for _some_ choice of distinct $x_k$'s in this range, then it's invertible for _all_ such distinct $x_k$'s. But one still needs to verify the premise.

Comment: The determinant is not always vanishing as $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)=\frac{2n}{2^n}$ is not zero. So the initial determinant is not zero picking $x_i = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi k}{n}$.

Comment: The $x$'s you quote are distributed from $\pi/2$ to $-\pi/2$ as $k$ ranges from $0$ to $n$, not $0$ to $\pi$. So either you're using a different indexing for $k$ or this example doesn't work.